# IF Statement + OR Dilemma

Tags: excel

I have this as a dataset:

[image]

I'm having a hard time trying to make a new column to do this.

- If there is a duplicate in the user name, see if TF = TRUE, then check to see if VERSION is either "Boxing 2007" OR "Boxing 2010", if it is either of those, return "FLAG IT", if not return "OK"

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Using structured references, and assuming the `T/F` column is Boolean:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF([Username],[@Username])>1, [@[T/F]],
OR([@Version]="Boxing 2007",[@Version]="Boxing 2010")),
"FLAG IT","OK")
```